# Referring to class attributes of a generic type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have an abstract base class which defines several class attributes which are types themselves (i.e., nested types); the attributes are overridden in concrete derived classes inheriting from the abstract class. The concrete derived classes are used with several other classes which are type-annotated as generics, where the type parameter has a type constraint that it must be derived from the abstract class. I want these other classes (generics) to refer to the class attributes (nested types) of the concrete classes. The following example should demonstrate the idea:

```
import typing

class Base:
    A: typing.Type[Base]

class One(Base):
    class A(Base):  # overrides Base.A
        pass

class Two(Base):
    class A(One):  # overrides Base.A
        pass


T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=Base)

class Foo(typing.Generic[T]):                 # the generic
    def foo(self, a: typing.Type[T.A]) -> T:  # <-- here, see T.A
        ...

f: Foo[Two] = Foo()
f.foo(Two.A)        # line 22 is here
```

MyPy v0.701 reports an error on line 22:

> Argument 1 to "foo" of "Foo" has incompatible type "Type[A]"; expected "Type[Two]"

MyPy seems to ignore the attribute reference at `T.A`. How do I make it understand that I am trying to refer to the type available via the attribute `.A`? The attribute is guaranteed to be available because the type variable `T` is constrained to `Base`, which has `A`. Note that extending the set of generic types is not an option; I could elaborate on this but the explanation would be too specific to my application.

**UPDATE:** MyPy v0.711 with `--new-semantic-analyzer` yields a more comprehensible error message:

> Name 'T.A' is not defined

Comment: Note that your invocation of f.foo *is* incorrect, even though not for the reason stated by mypy. You pass in an instance of Type[A], but your annotation requires just an instance of A.

Comment: Is the body of foo actually ..., or do you have an implementation that might constrain T.A to T?

Comment: Yes indeed, I have messed up the example while stripping it of unrelated details specific to my application, sorry. The body of `foo` is complex and is not shown here; it requires a particular implementation of A defined inside the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or not but if you parameterize the argument bound to Base it works:

```py
class Base:
    A: typing.Type['Base']


class One(Base):
    class A(Base):  # overrides Base.A
        pass


class Two(Base):
    class A(One):  # overrides Base.A
        pass


T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound='Base')
A = typing.TypeVar('A', bound='Base')


class Foo(typing.Generic[T, A]):    # the generic
    def foo(self, a: typing.Type[A]) -> T:  # <-- here, see T.A
        pass


f: Foo[Two, Two.A] = Foo()
f.foo(Two.A)        # line 22 is here
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as I mentioned at the very end of my question, adding a new type parameter is highly undesirable because it makes the user-facing API unnecessarily complex. At that point, I expect the user might be tempted to just plaster the code with `# type: ignore` rather than dealing with type parameters. Perhaps I should just post my code here in its entirety for an in-depth review?

Comment: I'm stumped. I thought it might have something to do with covariance but adding that property to the TypeVar didn't seem to help. What's most weird is the error message `expected "Type[Two]"` like it's just ignoring the `.A` part of the Type parameter. It feels almost like a lexer error in MyPy.